# h264 Licensing, ffmpeg iPhone transcoding

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-capture, transcoding

**Requirements**

 1. An application that should run, to begin with, on iPhone, and, in the end on a plurality
    of SmartPhone devices.
 2. Aim at having the trans-coding code supporting as much OSs as possible.
 3. Application is commercial.

**Use-case**

 I.  Record video using the portable SmartPhone Camera application
 II. Trans-code the video into a plurality of bit-rates using a cutom app

**iPhone Implementation**

 A. To satisfy requirement [2], Implement Trans-coding using C++
 B. Use ffmpeg for trans-coding.

**Problem**
 - Using ffmpeg to encode H264 req usage of the x264 lib
 - H264 encoding mandate payment for Licensing.

**In order to avoid H264 Licensing**
 - The iPhone device ( and many others ) come with built-in H264 encoding capability
 - Usage of the built-in H264 Codec will avoid licensing problems/restrictions

---

*Does ffmpeg, supports, in any way, usage of iPhone's built-in H264 encoder ?*



Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 'Aim at having the trans-coding code supporting as much OSs as possible.' sounds like a dream

Comment: Why does it? assuming the only part changing is the H264 encoder and the rest eg. MP4 demuxing is done using ffmpeg.

Comment: @NadaRub you can't target ios and platform independence at the same time. forget about it.

Comment: independence == only for the trans-coding module, thus, a .SO or .a, the rest, obviously is quite platform dependent

Comment: Both the hardware and license issues covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606933/using-ffmpeg-to-display-video-on-iphone/17622379#17622379

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Encoding.com's HLS offering.

http://www.encoding.com/help/article/easily_create_iphone_streaming_files_with_encodingcom

Comment: I don't need HLS, rather, I merely need to be able to transcode an existing file into multiple different bit-rates, it appears that I have no choice BUT to use the ALAssetWriter/Reader Obj-C objects having this iPhone specific

Answer (score 0):

The AVFoundation framework provides a mechanism to write H264 encoded video to a file (mp4 or quicktime container format). You can attempt to parse the video file and extract the H264 NALs as they're being written.

It's a little bit tricky, but it should be doable.