# using ffmpeg to display video on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ffmpeg, video-streaming

anyone can help me on this ?

I have this API

```
ret = avRecvFrameData(avIndex, buf, VIDEO_BUF_SIZE, (char *)&frameInfo, sizeof(FRAMEINFO_t), &frmNo);
```

the buffer will fill with the content from the video thread the codec is **H264** frameInfo contains the related information. If I want to display on iPhone, how to do it with ffmpeg?

much appreciated with your help .

Comment: If the codec is h.264, why don't you use media player framework or av foundation framework which will be hardware accelerated?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I just checked the Media Player Framework and AV Foundation Framework. It seems the framework load data either from File or URL and display the video.  For my case, I am getting the video data from the IP camera API. What is available is the ( buffer data about the frame, frame info indicate it is i-frame / b-frame, and the codec type). With all these information, any framework / API can recommend me to display this as a streaming video on iPhone?

Comment: You should check out [AVBasicVideoOutput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project.  It shows you how to create OpenGL ES textures from pixel buffer, and so on.  HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using ffmpeg in an iOS for a number of reasons. First, there are real [license issues](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304015542/http://multinc.com/2009/08/24/compatibility-between-the-iphone-app-store-and-the-lgpl/) that put including ffmpeg in a legal grey area when it comes to iOS apps. Second, performance will be very very poor. Third, iOS already includes APIs that have access to the h.264 hardware on the device. You can find my example Xcode project at [AVDecodeEncode](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVDecodeEncode), this is an example of using my library to decode from h.264 and then encode back to h.264.

Comment: thanks for the information, I believe AVAnimator is a nice framework. I am trying this example project. is there any API on how to use this framework ?

Comment: More info is available on the website or my blog, but stackoverflow is not really the right place for this discussion since it is not really Q + A about the original question.